# Ode to convergence

Tags: formation-of-numbers, poetry

> ```
>   Taking a numeral core
>   (digits: a non-quad four)
>       digits I ordered, then
>       lesser I minused, till
>   evolve I couldn't more.
> ```

What is this unfathomably clunky poem all about?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're referring to:

> [**Kaprekar's routine**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaprekar%27s_routine)
>
>  *Quoting from the linked Wikipedia article:*
>  Kaprekar's routine is an algorithm in recreational mathematics which produces a sequence of numbers which either converges to a **constant value** or results in a **repeating cycle**. The algorithm is as follows:
>
>   1. Choose any natural number $n$ in some base (usually base 10). This is the first number of the sequence.
>   2. Create a new number $n′$ by arranging the digits of $n$ in descending order, and another new number $n″$ by arranging the digits of $n$ in ascending order.
>   3. These numbers may have leading zeros, which can be discarded (or alternatively, retained). Subtract $n′ − n″$ to produce the next number of the sequence.
>   4. Repeat step 2.
>
>   For example, if we start with $3524$ then we get:
>  $$5432 − 2345 = 3087$$ 
>  $$8730 − 378 = 8352$$ 
>  $$8532 − 2358 = 6174$$ 
>  $$7641 − 1467 = 6174$$

A few more points:

> - The title refers to the convergence of the number as one of the exit conditions
>  - The riddle is written in like an algorithm, with the two indented lines representing a loop that is initialized with the line preceding it, and the exit criteria as the line that follows it

And a credit to [Florian Bourse's answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/62181/33080) for these points:

> - [Kaprekar's constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/6174_(number)) is 6174, and each line in the verse consists of words of length 6, 1, 7 and 4.
>  - The only numbers which when subject to Kaprekar's routine don't converge at 6174 are numbers composed of the same digit (e.g. 1111).
>  - This ties in to Bass's comment about the poker hand.

Comment: Everything you say, is of course true, and very much intended. There are a couple of other things I'd really like to see: one is essential for explaining the second line of the poem, and the other one is crucial for saving my reputation as a poet.

Comment: For the second line... is quad referring to a quadruple or quad tuple, to reference the 4 digits?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question, but to remove any ambiguity, the intended meaning of "non-quad four" is "any 4 digits that wouldn't beat a full house as a poker hand" :-)

Answer (score 7):

Building on [Phylyp's answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/62176/43840) :

> All 4 digits numbers except quadruples lead to Kaprekar's constant 6174 when we apply the algorithm described.
>  Note that each line of the riddle shows words of respectively 6, 1, 7, and 4 letters, reminding us of the fix-point of the algorithm, which makes for the beauty of the riddle.

Comment: Beauty, indeed :-) (and yes, these were exactly the things I meant in my comment to @Phylyp 's answer.)

Comment: Nice - I didn't see the 6-1-7-4 pattern in the verse :-)