# Oh, one short ode of love

Tags: wordplay, visual, steganography, poetry, letters

> ```
>     I'm to grow in mind
>     If now onto learning;
>     And to show understanding,
>     We cannot be blind.
> ```

Where is the heart? :)

---

<sup>Inspired by [this](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/62175/ode-to-convergence) (thanks @[Bass](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/36023/bass)!)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the upvotes! To be honest, I was a little scared to post this after not being on Puzzling.SE for awhile due to busy priorities... but I now realise I was worrying over nothing. Funny how I find this site to be a sense of freedom whilst most of my friends outside of this community find the puzzles here to be mentally abusing! I don't know if you realise how smart you all really are, and the things I have learnt from you guys. With that being said, I want to thank you the most on behalf of that, hence why I have returned, and will remain here for awhile :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Every word in the title contains an *o*, and the *o*'s in the poem form a heart:
>
>  [image: heart]

Comment: Everything is too easy on Puzzling. Good job on getting the answer! :D **A note to other users:** I will not be accepting this until the next $24$ hours, so you can still have a shot :)

Comment: _"I will not be accepting this until the next 24 hours, so you can still have a shot :)"_ Why? The correct answer is already given. There are no shots to have here.

Comment: @NicolasB well, the correct answer is also hidden with the spoiler quote, so you don't know what the answer is unless you are willing to check for yourself. Also, if you find another answer that is just as good, I'll give it a bounty (I enforce this rule with all my questions).

Comment: _"Good job on getting **the** answer!"_ by user477343

Comment: @NicolasB This is the *intended* answer. There might be another answer (I suspect it's very unlikely, though) but yes you are right — this is the answer. I still don't see how this would affect other users wanting to figure out the puzzle, but. Must I repeat that this answer is *hidden* unless one makes the action to have it revealed to their very eyes. It does not matter to one attempting to solve the puzzle if someone else found the answer, unless that person gives up or figures out the answer and wishes to verify it... or if they only want to answer to potentially get a checkmark, I guess.

Comment: @NicolasB Don't feel discouraged to answer the puzzle because someone else did it and got it right, if that's what you are implying, unless you already looked at this answer of course.

Comment: Congratulations, noedne! $(+1)\,\color{green}{\checkmark}$